# Yii2 не создается папка vendor при установке

Tags: yii2

Yii2 не создается папка vendor при установке.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-installation.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что в корне проекта лежит заполненный файл composer.json и выполните в консоли `composer update`. После этого создастся папка vendor со всеми описанными в файле модулями.